# TextView live text changed as format dd/mm/yyyy using c#

Tags: android, date, xamarin, textview

In UWP c# in textbox.textchange event I'm using code like that

```
public static void wpisywanie_daty(TextBox sender)
    {
        var nowyWpis = "";
        var plainText = sender.Text.Replace("/", "");
        if (plainText.Length <= 5)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= plainText.Length; i++)
            {
                nowyWpis += plainText[i - 1];
                if (i % 2 == 0) nowyWpis += "/";
            }
            sender.Text = nowyWpis;
            sender.Select(sender.Text.Length, 0);
        }
        if (sender.Text.Length >= 10)
        {
            sender.IsEnabled = false;
            sender.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

changing dinamicly text to format dd/mm/yyyy when you typing.
How to implement it in android c# xamarin?

When the code hit line sender.Text = nowyWpis; it rise textchanged eventhandler and start code from beginning.

Comment: I don't understand, do you need a data picker control or do you need `EditText` for text entering?

Comment: Both. EditText is a data picker in my application